# Print percent character

Tags: javascript

```
console.log("%test"); // %test
console.log("%%test"); // %test
console.log("%%%test"); // %%test
etc
```

Say I have a string that may or may not have a number of consecutive '%'
How can I print it correctly (with all percent characters)?

Example:

```
var myString = getStringFromAnAPi();  // say, the API returns "ping%%%pong"
console.log(myString)   // ping%%pong   -> missing one %
```

Comment: What browser are you using ? With only one argument, Chrome doesn't seem to consider it as a format.

Comment: its working here http://jsfiddle.net/bprVC/. I checked with Chrome and mozilla.

Comment: I checked in chrome console, works alright. Which browser you are using.

Comment: Did you try to backslash it ("\%")?

Comment: If you'll print right to html, you can try replacing by special code `&#37;`.. so `&#37;test`. I'm shooting in the dark, not sure if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by: `console.log('%s%%%', 'test');`. See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8B5Vh/

Comment: Question, but why are % signs disappearing in the first place. I'm using NodeJS in my console and noticing this bug. It's not a big deal but its a mild nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

this way you can append text to %,

```
console.log("%",'test'); // %test
console.log("%%","test"); // %test
console.log("%%%","test"); // %%test
```

in html,

```
<div>&#37;test</div>
<div>&#37;&#37;test</div>
<div>&#37;&#37;&#37;test</div>
```

**output**

```
%test
%%test
%%%test
```